# OneDrive vanished completely from the machine

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I use OneDrive, but recently it vanished from my machine.

And by vanished, I mean it's completely gone.

I checked this folder:

`%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive`

It has 0 files, 0 bytes.

I checked Add/Remove programs, it's not in the list.  Nor is it in the list of Windows components to install.

It's not in Task Manager's startup list.  There are no OneDrive related services in the services manager.

What happened here?

I did nothing to uninstall it, but it's gone.  Completely gone.

How can I get this back on the machine?

Comment: If you still have `%Systemroot%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe`, run it to reinstall OneDrive. (Or `%Systemroot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe`)

Comment: @harrymc I found it in `%Systemroot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe` ... thanks.   If you post that as the answer I will accept.

Comment: @harrymc For the record, running says it needs an update, which directed me to https://g.msn.com/1rewlive5skydrive/skydrivesetup

Comment: I've added an answer, although with a different download address.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks I accepted it as OneDrive is working again now.  Why it completely disappeared from my machine is another question.  It seemed to happen after a Cumulative Update to Windows 10.  Who knows.

Comment: @harrymc Upvote my question if you can, as it is a valid issue and you do have a valid answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted, although this doesn't affect the positioning of the post in google answers, where superuser.com is highly positioned.

Comment: @harrymc Nope but it gives me 20 reputation :)  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OneDrive installation can be found in
`%Systemroot%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe` or
`%Systemroot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe`,
depending on whether Windows is 32-bit or 64-bit.

If missing, the installation can also be downloaded from
[here](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-au/download/).